# How to Serialize Object to Xml

Tags: c#, xml, save

The class I want to store:

```
[Serializable]
public class Storagee
{
    int tabCount;
    List<string> tabNames;
    List<EachItemListHolder> eachItemsHolder;

    public void PreSetting(int count, List<string> strings, List<EachItemListHolder> items)
    {
        tabCount = count;
        tabNames = strings;
        eachItemsHolder = items;
    }

    public void PreSetting(int count )  //debug purpose
    {
        tabCount = count;       
    }

    public int GetTabCount() { return tabCount; }
    public List<string> GetTabNames() { return tabNames; }
    public List<EachItemListHolder> GetListEachItemListHolder() { return eachItemsHolder; }

}
```

Serializing class:

```
namespace Book
{
    class SaveAndLoad
    {
        public void SaveAll(Storagee str)
        {
            var path = @"C:\Temp\myserializationtest.xml";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Storagee));
                xSer.Serialize(fs, str);
            }

        }

        public Storagee LoadAll()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Temp\myserializationtest.xml";

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) //double  
            {
                XmlSerializer _xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Storagee));

                var myObject = _xSer.Deserialize(fs);

                return (Storagee)myObject;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Main method (Window form):

```
class Book
{
    List<EachTab> eachTabs;
    Storagee storagee;
    SaveAndLoad saveAndLoad;
    eachTabs = new List<EachTab>();
    storagee = new Storagee();
    saveAndLoad = new SaveAndLoad();


    void Saving() 
    {
        int count = UserTab.TabCount;     // tab counts
        storagee.PreSetting(count);
        saveAndLoad.SaveAll(storagee); 
    }

}
```

It makes xml file but doesn't save data.

I tried the serializing code in different project and it worked.

but it doesn't in this solution

since I'm kind of new to coding I don't know what the problem is

especially serializing part.

serializing codes are copied and pasted with little tweak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It makes xml file but doesn't save data.

It doesn't save any data because your class does not provide any data that it can serialize. `XmlSerializer` only serializes public fields and properties and the `Storagee` class doesn't have any.

You could, for example, change your public getter methods to public properties:

```
public int TabCount { get; set; }
public List<string> TabNames { get; set; }
public List<string> EachItemsHolder { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, if using public properties is not an option, you could also look into using custom serialization by implementing [IXmlSerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).